# QML declare IDs in a property var and assign values inside a Repeater component

Tags: qml, repeater, variant

I want to define the id's of a component which is part of a repeater, but I don't know how to read the values, and if they should be declared as strings...

```
property var example: ["A", "B", "C"]

Repeater {
    id:idRepeater
    model: 3

    Rectangle {
        AnotherComponent {id: example[modelData]}
    }
}
```

`example[modelData]` is giving error.

I also tried declaring `model:["A", "B", "C"]` and assigning `AnotherComponent{id:ModelData}`, but it is not working either.

Comment: It's not possible. It doesn't make a lot of sense too, since the ids won't be accessible outside of each delegate. Each delegate has its own context that can't be accessed by the rest of your code. I suggest rethinking your structure if you needed that.

Comment: thanks @GrecKo, is there any way to access to functions inside a delegate? or to connect signals between the main component and the child (so when the main component emits a signal, the child signal will call the function)?

Comment: You could use [`Connections`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-connections.html) inside each delegate with the `target` set as your main component

Comment: @GrecKo, I'm not sure how to define the target. If I set it to parent inside AnotherComponent.qml, it is giving problems, and if I define connection inside the  Rectangle (which is the delegate of repeater), then AnotherComponent.qml is not receiving the connection... Any tip?